# I am getting errors with npm i, and node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I cloned a React project and when I run `npm i` or `npm i <packageName>` I get a bunch of errors.  Running `npm i` I can see the `node_modules` folder created until the errors start pouring in the terminal and the `node_modules` folder disappears.

I've added the Terminal errors, `package.json` and my project directory tree below.

- I recently upgraded my mac OS from Sierra to Big Sur 11.2.3
- npm -v 7.6.3
- node -v v15.12.0

**Errors:**

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.12.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@15.12.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.3 and node@15.12.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.2 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alearanibar/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.12.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/alearanibar/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.12.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/alearanibar/Library/Caches/node-gyp/15.12.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
npm ERR! No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1500, in XcodeVersion
npm ERR!     version_list = GetStdoutQuiet(["xcodebuild", "-version"]).splitlines()
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1563, in GetStdoutQuiet
npm ERR!     raise GypError("Error %d running %s" % (job.returncode, cmdlist[0]))
npm ERR! gyp.common.GypError: Error 1 running xcodebuild
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 51, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 670, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 662, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 647, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2451, in GenerateOutput
npm ERR!     writer.Write(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 831, in Write
npm ERR!     self.WriteSources(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 1302, in WriteSources
npm ERR!     cflags = self.xcode_settings.GetCflags(
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 661, in GetCflags
npm ERR!     archs = self.GetActiveArchs(self.configname)
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 515, in GetActiveArchs
npm ERR!     xcode_archs_default = GetXcodeArchsDefault()
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 122, in GetXcodeArchsDefault
npm ERR!     xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1511, in XcodeVersion
npm ERR!     version = CLTVersion()  # macOS Catalina returns 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
npm ERR!   File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1549, in CLTVersion
npm ERR!     return re.search(regex, output).groupdict()["version"]
npm ERR! AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.12.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v88"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.12.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v88-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alearanibar/codingcfv/reactpractice/react-mastery/graphql-lesson/node_modules/grpc
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alearanibar/.npm/_logs/2021-04-02T06_27_30_990Z-debug.log
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "crwn-clothing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "6.0.2",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "2.6.3",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "reselect": "4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production":[ \[][1]
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Project directory:**

```
graphql-lesson/
├── public
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   └── ...
    ├── components
    │   └── ...
    ├── firebase
    │   └── ...
    ├── pages
    │   └── ...
    ├── redux
    │   └── ...
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── serviceWorker.js
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── package.json
    └── README.md
```

Comment: You should try with a lts version of node and npm 6.*. For this install nvm then run `nvm install lts` or `nvm install 14`. This will install node 14 with npm 6.14.*

Comment: I've been using this computer for a year and have not used nvm , I've only used npm and yarn.  Do I have to use nvm now?

Comment: nvm allows only to change of node environment and version very quickly. You can do the same things manually

Comment: @Troopers unfortunately, downgrading the node version didn't work

Answer (score 3):

Your output says

> No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'

You need to install XCode or at least [comandline tools](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/macxcodecommandlinetools.html)

Comment: I see command line tools for Xcode 12.4 would you recommend that one, it's the latest thats not in beta?  for mac OS from Sierra to Big Sur 11.2.3